# Extension method at Linq statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4

Please see below:

```
public Content GetContentByPageTitle(string pageTitle)
{
    return _db.Contents.FirstOrDefault(
            x => hnUrlHelper.UrlSafe(x.PageTitle).Equals(pageTitle)
        );
}


public class hnUrlHelper
{
    public static string UrlSafe(string value)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            value = value.Replace("Š", "s");

            value = value.Trim().ToLower();

            value = value.Replace(" ", "-");

            value = Regex.Replace(value, @"[^A-Za-z0-9-_]", "");

            return value.Trim().ToLower();
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>           LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String UrlSafe(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'System.String UrlSafe(System.String)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.
>
> Source Error:

I am trying to work out UrlSafe method within Linq statement. This shows error like below.
Is there anyone know how to turns out this to working, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use an extension method for the most part, but I don't think you can do something for the regex part.

The best I could approach is something like that.

```
public static T FirstOrDefaultUrlSafe<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, string>> propertyExpression, string pageTitle)
        {
            var parameter = propertyExpression.Parameters[0];
            var propertyName = (propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
            Expression body = parameter;
            body = Expression.Property(body, propertyName);
            body = Expression.Call(body, "Replace", null, new[] { Expression.Constant("Š"), Expression.Constant("s") });
            body = Expression.Call(body, "ToLower", null);
            body = Expression.Call(body, "Trim", null);
            body = Expression.Call(body, "Replace", null, new[] { Expression.Constant(" "), Expression.Constant("-") });
            body = Expression.Equal(body, Expression.Constant(pageTitle));
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, new[] { parameter });
            return queryable.FirstOrDefault(lambda);
        }
```

usage in your case :

```
return _db.Contents.FirstOrDefaultUrlSafe(x => x.PageTitle, pageTitle)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells you that your method can't be translated into SQL. In this case, there is **no way to fix it**, because the method uses `Regex` which can't be translated to SQL either.

A common way to fix such exceptions would be to have a property or method that returns an expression:

```
Expression<Func<Content,bool>> EqualsUrl(string url)
{
    return c => c.PageTitle.Replace("Š", "s") == url;
}
```

called like so:

```
_db.Contents.FirstOrDefault(EqualsUrl(pageTitle))
```

As long as you use `Replace`, `ToLower`, `Trim` and similar methods that EF *can* translate into SQL you're OK. But, as said, the `Regex` is the show stopper here.